# How do I change the WordPress Address URL only and still login to wp-admin

Tags: wp-admin, cdn, amazon

The story so far:
I added a distribution on **Amazon CloudFront** (randomString.cloudfront.net), then added a **cname** (cdn.mydomain.com) and finally created a cname record on the DNS server - pointing cdn.mydomain.com to randomString.cloudfront.net.

Next, I changed the Wordpress Address (URL) in General sittings to switch all URLs in my theme from mydomain.com to cdn.mydomain.com, the site loads amazingly fast.

The contents are served from AWS Cloudfront; however, I am unable to login to wp-admin (probably coz the 'Site Address' is still mydomain.com.

If I switch both WordPress Address and Site Address - the site fails to load with the error: multiple redirects.

How can I achieve this? Use the cdn.mydomain.com as WordPress URL and still login to wp-admin - Is this even possible?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else in this dilemma, I took a different approach

I set the origin as cdn.mydomain.com on AWS Cloudfront and added cname www.mydomain.com

all working now :)